# Wanted to create recruiting app but number of users are limited in Developer Edition

Tags: developer-edition

I wanted to create the recruiting app from the work book but the number of users (2) are limited in the developer edition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The workbook only requires two licenses-- the system administrator (the default account) and the other user. It explicitly says so in the workbook on Page 4 (PDF, current version). Deactivate your other active user in your current Developer Edition, or simply create a new Developer Edition org (they are free). If you are an ISV/partner, log into the Partner Portal and create a ISV Developer Org, which has 20 licenses available.

Answer (score 1):

You can create up to 10 new users for your Recruiting App in Development by using the Identity User License.
Search: Company Information - User Licenses, you should have 10 free

1-create a profile called "Recruiter Identity User" or whatever you want to call it
2-create and assign all your Recruiter App users to this profile.
3-enable "Login" link under Users (allows you to quickly login as another user for testing)

This setup works great for understanding security, fls, owd,
role hierarchy, sharing rules, etc.